# How to enable VMX in the HAXM installation?

Tags: android-studio, intel, hyper-v, haxm

This is frustrating af. My problem seems not to be unique as you can see, there are a lot of similar issues opened here in SO but after playing trial and error for i-dont-know-how-many-hours i give up.

Some quick context:

Installed Android Studio. Created my first ADV. Lunch it and then, this appears:

[image]

Tried to install HAXM from the AS settings option (Tools> SDK Manager> SDK Tools and click on the Intel x86 Emulator...). The installation failed:

[image]

Surprised, i went to that path only to check that there was a HAXM installer. Run it and got this:

[image]

So, I think It's obvious that I have to enable that option but I don't know how since all i cand find isn't related to my case.  No, I don't use an AMD processor, and yes, I have the "Hyper-V" option desactived in the "Turn Windows features on/off" panel.

Do you guys can help me?

EDIT: I've also desactivated the assisted virtualization option in the settings panel of Avast.

Comment: Did you check your BIOS settings?  HW virtualization can be disabled by the BIOS (in a way that it can't be re-enabled without a reset) to prevent malware from having even the possibility of setting itself up a a hypervisor.

Comment: That was! Thanks! @PeterCordes

Answer (score 14):

This is for my asus laptop.
You have to enter bios, enable VMX.
Here are the steps

---

1. Press Del or F2 into BIOS after power on.
2. Press F7 for getting into Advanced Mode.
3. Click CPU configurations in Advanced.
4. You will see Intel (VMX) Virtualization Technology, enable it.

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Dell Precision 3541

---

I got the same error as you when trying to install HAXM, but my bios does not have an explicit setting for "VMX". This is what solved it for me :

1. Ensure in Bios  all "Virtualization" features are turned on.
2. Go to "Turn Windows features On/Off" and turn off (uncheck) Hypervisor.
3. Open a cmd prompt as admin and run : bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
4. Restart and try HAXM install again.

Answer (score 1):

###### This is for ThinkPad

---

1. Press "Enter" on system startup & enter BIOS
2. Click on Security
3. Click on Virtualization
4. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology
5. F10 (save & exit)

Answer (score 1):

My PC is: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400` with `UHD Graphics 630`, and motherboard is `MSI H510M-A PRO (MS-7D22) (U3E1)`

---

I spent a couple of days working on this problem since none of the solutions provided here (and other placed) worked for me. I was able to find a solution following this clue from the actual `haxm` GitHub repository.

[There](https://github.com/intel/haxm#status) we read:

> HAXM was created to bring Intel Virtualization Technology to Windows and macOS users. Today both Microsoft Hyper-V and macOS HVF have added support for Intel Virtual Machine Extensions. We have therefore decided to retire the HAXM project. HAXM v7.8.0 is our last release and we will not accept pull requests or respond to issues after this.

ANSWER: What this is basically saying is that we need to fully enable Hyper-V to make this work, since the HAXM technology, as far as 2023, has been *FULLY INTEGRATED* into Windows. And the `intel/haxm` repository is archived.

---

### MORE ON THIS

#### 1) The error

I was reading the following log while trying to install unsuccessfully `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` from Android's SDK Manager:

```
Version: 7.6.5
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM
Extract: checktool.exe... 100%
Execute: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       *  Yes
VMX enabled         -  No
EPT supported       *  Yes
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    *  Yes
OS version          *  Windows 10.0.22621
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
The system requirements are not satisfied.
```

Same log as the main question.

This is the SDK window, by the way.

[image]

NOTE: As you can see, it is installed in my computer.

#### 2) Get the Hyper-V

In my Windows 11 system, I searched for `Turn Windows feature on or off`, and enabled all related Hyper-V technologies:

[image]

Keep in mind that I was not able to turn on `Hyper-V Hypervisor` until after I enabled the other Hyper-V technologies and I restarted the system.

#### 3) Check the BIOS

Also, you'll need to enable this technologies at firmware level, this is, the BIOS.

[image]

You may also need to enable `Execute Disable Bit` (also know in some systems as either: XD, Excute Disable, No Execute, or Hardware DEP. I read about that somewhere, but I don't even how to do it in my system, and I don't remember doing it. Just keep this paragraph as a side note.

[image]

#### 4) Result

Finally, I was able to install it from the SDK:

[image]

#### 5) Final thoughts

I don't know why this `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` installation is still required. One would assume that enabling `Hyper-V` would be enough. But that's not the case. I think that this may be related to some additional settings required by the SDK.

```
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)".
Warning: Package "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) should be installed in 
"C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" but 
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2" instead.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_6_5.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" complete.
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\34.0.0\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2\package.xml
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2' (Expected 'C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager')
Warning: Already observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in 'C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2'
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\cwm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installed successfully!
Done
```