# Haxm failed to install due to unsupported VMX

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, haxm, vt-x

So my android virtual device is not working and I have to install HAXM for it to work again properly. I found some solutions and I followed it. I unchecked the Hyper-v and enabled the virtualization in my BIOS but the installation failed. I am currently using AMD Ryzen 5 3400g. All the requirements was met except the VMX supported

> **VMX supported - No**

> **VMX enabled - Yes**

Here is the screenshot of the installation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67635516/haxm-not-installing-due-to-system-requirements/67661654#67661654.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67661654/7389293) (thanks for `nevilad` in the comments for the link).

> HAXM does not support AMD.

Additional information ([source](https://github.com/intel/haxm#status)):

> HAXM was created to bring Intel Virtualization Technology to Windows and macOS users. Today both Microsoft Hyper-V and macOS HVF have added support for Intel Virtual Machine Extensions. We have therefore decided to retire the HAXM project. HAXM v7.8.0 is our last release and we will not accept pull requests or respond to issues after this.

Comment: I provided more information about this error in Intel processors, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76767321/7389293